# (Actionscript 3) How to Hide Right Click Menu?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I found a cheat to one of my games in which you could access a screen you are not supposed to by right clicking and clicking on "Play". 
I tried typing in the following code:

```
var cm:ContextMenu=new ContextMenu(); 
cm.builtInItems.play=false;
```

but it is still not removing that item. Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Comment: Does your game use `gotoAndPlay()` to show this level? Is your code written on different frames or is written in one place like single Class package? I cannot imagine it still happens if you're using something like `addChild(Level_MovieClip)` or `if (someCondition == isTrue) { show_Hidden_Screen(); }`. I think `PLAY` on _Flash Player_ menu is just going to the next frame in your project's timeline. If using IDE, Does your project have multiple frames in your timeline?

Comment: I use 'gotoAndStop()' to show the level. I only typed that code on the first frame and yes, my project has multiple frames.

Comment: Your app & code should exist on one (first) frame only. Use MovieClip objects to display other parts of app. You can **cut** frames from stage timeline and **paste** into MClip's timeline. Look into _AS3 linkage_ for how to use an MClip from library by code. Instead of telling stage `gotoAndStop(x)`, you simply addChild the MClip or even tell that MC to got to specific frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to apply the context menu.

```
stage.contextMenu = cm
```